# Mapstruct nested bean with expression

Tags: mapstruct

I expect to device bean to set every property to target bean as in the documentation. What is wrong here?

> If you don’t want explicitly name all properties from nested source bean, you can use . as target. This will tell MapStruct to map every property from source bean to target object. The following shows an example:

```
  @Mapping(target = ".",  qualifiedByName = "device")
  public abstract ClientRegisterDeviceRequest toDeviceRequest(RegisterDeviceRequest registerDeviceRequest);

  @Named("device")
  public DeviceInfo getDevice() {
    return DeviceInfoService.get();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. However, using `@Mapping(target = ".")` needs to have `source` defined. Otherwise, MapStruct has no way of knowing what it needs to map.

What I would suggest to do is something like:

Perhaps you need something like:

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class MyMapper {

    public ClientRegisterDeviceRequest toDeviceRequest(RegisterDeviceRequest registerDeviceRequest) {
        return toDeviceRequest(regusterDeviceRequest, DeviceInfoService.get());
    }

    @Mapping(target = ".", source = "device")
    protected abstract ClientRegisterDeviceRequest toDeviceRequest(RegisterDeviceRequest registerDeviceRequest, DeviceInfo device);

}
```